# Getting nil from property

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 classes, `NSObject` class `DataParser` and a `ViewController`. In `DataParser` class I have some methods that parses XML and results are saved into an array which is a property of `DataParser` class. I want to show results to user in my `ViewController`. I have here this property `@property (strong, nonatomic) DataParser *parser;` and in `viewWillAppear` method I created instance of `DataParser` class and I'm trying to get array with results this way

```
self.parser = [[DataParser alloc] init];
[self.parser downloadBooksXML];
NSLog(@"%@", self.parser.array);
```

but I'm still getting nil. Does anyone know where could be the problem?

```
- (void)downloadBooksXML
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..."];

    [self downloadDataFromURL:url withCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data) {
        if (data) {
            self.xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
            self.xmlParser.delegate = self;
            self.foundValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            [self.xmlParser parse];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error");
        }
    }];
}
```

EDIT: When I nslog array in `DataParser` class in `parserDidEndDocument` method, it contains data

Comment: Can you please post your downloadBooksXML?

Comment: Do you have a custom init method for DataParser? If so, please post that too.

Comment: I don't, method is uploaded

Comment: What is nil exactly, I didn't get if it was `self.parser`, `data`, the parsing that is not calling the delegate methods, etc.

Comment: Nil is `self.parser.array`

Comment: you're setting array in a completionHandler (i.e. asynchronously in your XML parser I suppose), so no surprise that array is nil immediately after calling downloadBooksXML

Comment: What is the best way to access content of that array? Delegate? Notification? KVO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `[self.parser downloadBooksXML]` returns, `self.parser.array` has not been set yet, because the data has not been downloaded and parsed.

The data will be available once the document is done parsing, which you can check using the delegate method:

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    NSLog(@"%@", self.parser.array);
}
```

You can therefore use a pattern like this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.parser = [[DataParser alloc] init];
    [self.parser downloadBooksXML];
}

- (void) dataFinished {
    NSLog(@"%@", self.parser.array);
    // update the user interface
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
   [self dataFinished];
}
```

---

Depending on the implementation of your other code, you might need to switch to the main queue to update the UI:

```
- (void) dataFinished {
    NSLog(@"%@", self.parser.array);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        // update the user interface
    });
}
```

Comment: But this means I need to have all parser's methods in ViewController and DataParser class is useless then?

Comment: No, you could create a delegate and protocol if you want to keep them separate… just call `[self.delegate dataFinished];`

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're likely setting your DataParser array property somewhere in your XML parser, and that downloadBooksXML is performing the download and parsing asynchronously, you will find a nil value immediately upon return of the call to `downloadBooksXML`.

The delegation pattern suggested by @Aaron works.  You could also consider adding your own completion handler to your `downloadBooksXML` method, something like this:

```
typedef void (^DownloadBooksCompletionHandler)();

- (void)downloadBooksXMLWithCompletionHandler:(DownloadBooksCompletionHandler)completionHandler
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..."];

    [self downloadDataFromURL:url withCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data) {
        if (data) {
            self.xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
            self.xmlParser.delegate = self;
            self.foundValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            [self.xmlParser parse];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error");
        }

        completionHandler();         // <-- call the completionHandler!
    }];
}
```

then you can "notify" the caller when the download is complete by calling `completionHandler()`, and access the array and update your UI.

```
[self.parser downloadBooksXMLWithCompletionHandler:^()
{
  // now OK to access array property and update your UI
}];
```

you might also consider passing back an NSError * to the completion handler as a means of passing error info.

Lastly, beware of threading issues...`completionHandler()` will run on the thread called by your downloadDataFromURL completion handler.  Depending on your implementation, this may or may not be the UI thread.

Comment: This is what I would use.  Swift makes this type of delegation even easier and is very commonplace.

Answer (score -1):

NSXMLParser is XML parser (SAX type parser). It starts reading your XML from the beginning, and every time it finds a new element, a closing element or character data, it informs you about it. When parsing your example XML it will call it's delegates:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
  if (elementName == @"YourElement") {
    // save the elements of attributeDict in your array! This is the place where you add the object to your property self.parser.array!
  }
}
```

PS: If the guy who voted (-1) can tell me what was wrong in my answer?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but your answer has nothing to do with why the OP's array is nil.  You don't even mention how your code is to be implemented or how it would resolve the OP's problem.

Comment: Maybe because the question is so detailed and descriptive.  None of the other answers explain why the parser.array is nil! From what i understand the question is how to parse an XML and populate array of objects. The short answer is implement the NSXMLParser delegates methods.